# Use WebProfiler 3.2 in Symfony 2.7

Tags: javascript, symfony, fetch

I'm using Symfony 2.7 and don't plan on upgrading in 3.x or 4.x in the near future.

That said, i'm very interested in [this feature](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-web-debug-toolbar-and-profiler-improvements#added-support-for-window-fetch-calls) of the debug toolbar, in order to display the fetch api calls in the ajax calls summary :

> The Fetch JavaScript API provides an interface for fetching resources in a similar fashion to XMLHttpRequest/Ajax. However, the new API provides a more powerful and flexible feature set and that's why lots of developers are replacing Ajax with it.

For now, the "best" solution i could come up with was to copy/paste the relevant code from the [linked commit in the feature announcement](https://github.com/freshcells/symfony/blob/385279c29b5a3ef2f58e468a8e9e7885a9f2eb42/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/base_js.html.twig#L243) and tweak the Sfjs function right after the toolbar is loaded.

**It does work, and if it's the only solution i'm happy with it.** However I'm not totally comfortable in doing things this way.

Any ideas on a cleaner solution ?

I already thought of extending the debug toolbar functionnality and adding my own feature, but this doesn't seem that easy, and ideally I'd rather find a way of just using that commit code instead of copy pasting it

Comment: The best solution would be to upgrade to Sf 3 - if you modify code shipped with Symfony (through editing files in vendor/), you lose the ability to update Sf2.7 if any security updates are released within the next months

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would never edit the files in vendor/, right now i'm shimming the js function in my index file once the original function is loaded. And yeah, upgrading to sf3 would be great, unfortunately it's something I can't afford right now :)

Comment: If you update to Sf 2.8, you'll see deprecation notices. These need to be fixed to update to Sf3.x - for my applications, this needed some work, but was not a work for weeks. And putting your application on a more recent version of Symfony (2.7 is more than two years old) from time to time helps you to keep updating times minimal, compared to jumping from 2.7 to the most recent 4.0 which takes more time

Comment: Yeah I'll probably end up doing this. Thanks for the advice